# Working with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following XDocument:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:Office="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"    xmlns:Repl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl/" xmlns:Z="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:">
   <D:response>
       <D:href>http://aaa</D:href>
       <D:propstat>
           <D:prop>
               <D:displayname>a</D:displayname>
               <D:isFolder>t</D:isFolder>
           </D:prop>
           <D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
      </D:propstat>
  </D:response>
  <D:response>
        .
        .
  </D:response>
```

How can I get all the responses? (Everything under "D:response" tag, and obviously everything under "D:propstat" and "D:prop" tags - I want to get D:href, D:displayname, D:isFolder)

I'm doing this:

```
XNamespace d = "DAV:";
foreach (var file in doc.Descendants(d + "response"))
{
    if ((string)file.Element(d + "href") != (string)Configuration.Configs["baseUrl"])
    {
        string ref = (string)file.Element(d + "href");
        foreach (var propstat in file.Descendants(d + "propstat"))
            foreach (var prop in propstat.Descendants(d + "prop"))
            {
                string name = (string)prop.Element(d + "displayname");
                if (prop.Element(d + "isFolder") != null && (string)prop.Element(d + "isFolder") == "t")
                    string type = "folder";
                else
                    string type = "file";
            }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: The `D:` is a prefix which defines the namespace. You need to query for elements within that namespace; you can't just use the default namespace.

Comment: Is it possible that response will have several `propstat` elements? Or that propstat will have several `prop` or `status` elements? Also which elements could be missing in your xml?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. It's a bit clumsy but works

```
var result = doc.Descendants(d + "response")
                .Select(x => new { href = x.Element(d + "href"), nodes = x.Descendants(d + "prop") })
                .Select(y => new
   {
      href = (string)y.href.Value,
      displayname = (string)y.nodes.Select(z => z.Element(d + "displayname")).First().Value,
      isFolder = (string)y.nodes.Select(z => z.Element(d + "isFolder")).First().Value
   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In you scenario i'd strongly recommend the usage of [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

`\\D:response` gets all D:response elements in the document

`\\D:response\D:href` all href elements

`\\D:response\D:propstat\D:prop\D:displayname` all displayName elements

`\\D:response\D:propstat\D:prop\D:isFolder`all isFolder elements

if you need a relative path just drop the `\\`.
Please, read more about XPath in the link i provided. It will certainly be worth your investment.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce new range variables to simply your query:

```
XNamespace d = "DAV:";
var responses = from r in xdoc.Descendants(d + "response")
                let propstat = r.Element(d + "propstat")
                let prop = propstat.Element(d + "prop")
                let isFolder = (string)prop.Element(d + "isFolder")
                select new
                {
                    Href = (string)r.Element(d + "href"),
                    Status = (string)propstat.Element(d + "status"),
                    Name = (string)prop.Element(d + "displayname"),
                    Type = (isFolder == null || isFolder == "t") ? 
                           "folder" : "file"
                };
```

NOTE: This answer assumes that your response will have one `propstat` element with one `prop` element inside.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = File.ReadAllText("input.xml");
        var ns = "DAV:";
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        doc.Descendants(XName.Get("displayname", ns))
            .ToList().ForEach(dn =>
        {
            var isFolder = ((XElement)dn.NextNode).Value;
            var href = ((XElement)dn.Parent.Parent.PreviousNode).Value;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", href, dn.Value, isFolder);
        });
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
doc.Descendants(XName.Get("response", ns))
    .ToList().ForEach(r =>
{
    var href = r.Descendants(XName.Get("href", ns))
        .First().Value;
    r.Descendants(XName.Get("displayname", ns))
        .ToList().ForEach(dn => {
        var isFolder = ((XElement)dn.NextNode).Value;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", href, dn.Value, isFolder);
    });
});
```